# C++AMP:How does the iterator work

Tags: c++-amp, parallel-foreach

example:

```
parallel_for_each(mas.extend,[=](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
{
...
}
```

How does the index<1> idx work?
supposing,in mas: a set of numbers at array_view

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps don't think of the index as an iterator because that implies a sequential iteration through the container, but this is the parallel world so we're not starting at the beginning and going to the end.

```
index<1> idx
```

In your example, `idx` is a [index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305273.aspx) object of rank (dimension) 1. So it indexes into a one-dimensional [array_view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305260.aspx) container. i.e. `mas` also should be a one-dimensional.

```
array_view<const int, 1> mas;
```

Inside the parallel_for_each body, `idx` can be used if necessary to index into `mas`.

```
size_t i = idx[0]; 
int value = mas[i];
```

However in cases where the absolute position in the array_view is not important you don't need to make use of the index. Every item in `mas` will be processed.

If the array_view was for example a 2D matrix of values, then you would have an index of rank 2 rather, and then `idx[0]` would reference the rows and `idx[1]` would reference the columns for example.

I've found this free online book invaluable in understanding these concepts: [Parallel Programming with Microsoft Visual C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675934.aspx)